# HTML&CSS Strategy for header navigation

Tags: html, css, user-interface, responsive-design

[image]

Need input on how to best implement this navigation in HTML & CSS so that it is fluid when the user resizes the screen from 1200 to lets say 786px for example and so that the navigation options don't cram up  - then it will break to a hamburger situation. I do have the PSD file layered out and all.

My two ideas:

1. I'm thinking positioning the navigation at that position and then creating link areas over the navigation options
2. Making it so the big LOGO gets smaller and moves up while the navigation moves inward while the user make the screen smaller

Any ideas out there that could help with the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand why you would do the first idea. But the second idea could be easily accomplished and would help in getting your menu to fit on one line for browser window widths of 786px and higher.

Off the bat I see you might have issues with the stylized border. Fixed width graphics and fluid responsive design don't totally play well together. You'll probably want to create a set of menu border graphics for two breakpoints, one for 786px wide and up and one for what looks like 1200px wide. Perhaps one for your burger menu as well. If you're okay with sacrificing some of the design, you could create a horizontally repeating tile graphic or even a CSS3 gradient for the borders - otherwise you'll have fixed width menus with a set of graphics for each breakpoint - not ideal. Though, I can think of a trick you can do to fix that like using [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to restrict the width of the border elements for the different breakpoints you might want to use, using the same set of images then.

Anyway, you'd adjust the size of your menu items down for the mid-sized menu and as you've mentioned reduce the size of the logo, move it up, and remove the space in your list of links in the middle. How you go about doing the last part depends on your HTML structure for the links.

I'm currently doing a menu similar to yours for a project and have the below markup:

```
    <header id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav-toggle">
                <div class="hamburger">
                    <div class="bar"></div>
                    <div class="bar"></div>
                    <div class="bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="" class="logo"></a>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li><!--
                    --><li><a href="#">Restaurant</a></li><!--
                    --><li><a href="#">Menu</a></li><!--
                    --><li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li><!--
                    --><li><a href="#">Catering</a></li><!--
                    --><li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

I position the logo absolutely using my new go-to centering trick:

```
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 999;
}
```

I only have one menu breakpoint around 960px below which I do the hamburger menu. Here is my Sass/SCSS for that:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: $nav-breakpoint) {
    .list-inline {
        margin-left: -10px;

        li {
            display: inline-block;

            &:nth-child(3) {
                margin-right: 180px;
            }
        }

        a {
            padding-left: 15px;
            padding-right: 15px;
        }
    }
}
```

My strategy for creating the space in the middle where the logo sits is to apply a `margin-right` to the `nth-child` just before the logo. If you foresee that the number of menu items will never change this could work for you as well.

In my experience you can go smaller in the size of the menu links than you might think for devices that are in the 768px to 1024px width, and it's probably better to have smaller links that are spaced wider apart than bigger links that are crammed, making sure you're apply padding to the `a` tag rather than the `li` to increase the size of the "hit" area.

Let me know in the comments if you'd like any further exposition on anything I've suggested.